# Perl (MQSeries): How to connect to WMQ's channel with TLS (the "same code" works in C++)

Tags: perl, ssl, centos7, ibm-mq, tls1.2

I was tasked with implementing TLS support in one of our legacy perl scripts. It should be fairly simple but I failed (I am not able to connect to the queue manager through an encrypted channel). Could anyone tell me what am I missing?
My code in TestConnect.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use MQSeries;
use MQSeries::QueueManager;

my $qmgr = MQSeries::QueueManager->new(
  QueueManager => $ENV{MQMANAGER},
  AutoConnect  => 0,
  ClientConn   => {
    ChannelName => $ENV{MQCHANNEL},
    TransportType => 'TCP',
    ConnectionName => $ENV{MQHOSTNAME} . "(" . $ENV{MQPORT} . ")",
    SSLCipherSpec => $ENV{MQ_CIPH},
    Version => MQCD_VERSION_7
  },
  SSLConfig => {
    KeyRepository => $ENV{MQKEYR},
    CertificateLabel => $ENV{MQ_C_LABEL},
    Version => MQSCO_VERSION_5
  }
);

if (!$qmgr->Connect()) {
  print STDERR "Unable to connect to queue manager\nCompCode => " . $qmgr->CompCode() . "\nReason => " . $qmgr->Reason() . " (" . MQReasonToText($qmgr->Reason()) . ")\n";
}
else {
  print STDERR "\n\nALL OK!!\n\n"
}
```

Similar code in C++:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwrite-strings"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmqc.h>
#include <cmqxc.h>
#include <cmqstrc.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    MQHCONN hconn;
    MQLONG lCompCode=(MQLONG)0;
    MQLONG lReason=(MQLONG)0;

    MQCNO connectOpts = {MQCNO_DEFAULT};
    MQCD clientConn = {MQCD_CLIENT_CONN_DEFAULT};
    MQSCO sslConfig = {MQSCO_DEFAULT};

    connectOpts.Version = MQCNO_VERSION_5;
    strncpy(connectOpts.StrucId, MQCNO_STRUC_ID, 4);
    strcpy((char*)connectOpts.ConnTag, (const char*)MQCT_NONE);
    connectOpts.ClientConnPtr = &clientConn;
    connectOpts.SSLConfigPtr = &sslConfig;

    strcpy(clientConn.ChannelName, std::getenv("MQCHANNEL"));
    clientConn.TransportType = MQXPT_TCP;
    sprintf(clientConn.ConnectionName, "%s(%s)", std::getenv("MQHOSTNAME"), std::getenv("MQPORT"));
    strcpy(clientConn.SSLCipherSpec, std::getenv("MQ_CIPH"));
    clientConn.Version = MQCD_VERSION_7;

    strcpy(sslConfig.KeyRepository, std::getenv("MQKEYR"));
    strcpy(sslConfig.CertificateLabel, std::getenv("MQ_C_LABEL"));
    sslConfig.Version = MQSCO_VERSION_5;

    MQCONNX(std::getenv("MQMANAGER"), &connectOpts, &hconn, &lCompCode, &lReason);
    std::cout << "connection result " << MQCC_STR(lCompCode) << " with reason " << MQRC_STR(lReason) << "\n";

}
```

Please disregard strcpy instead of strncpy, not closing the connection and other less important things - I wanted the code to be as simple as possible (for the sake of tests).

All the environment variables above are set by me to proper values during execution, so that I can test the same connection details through Perl and through C++. I'm deliberately using non-standard names (e.g. avoid $MQSSLKEYR) to not pollute my environment with MQM variables, thus eliminating any possible side effects...

There are two tests: $MQCHANNEL points to a non-encrypted channel, with $MQ_CIPH empty: this works from both Perl and C++.
When I setup my $MQCHANNEL to point to a TLS-channel with $MQ_CIPH set accordingly, it works like a charm from C++ but in Perl, it shows:

```
MQCONN failed (Reason = 2393) (SSL initialization error.) at ./TestConnect.pl line 25.
Unable to connect to queue manager
CompCode => 2
Reason => 2393 (SSL initialization error.)
```

Unfortunately, the documentation is really vague and the error logs on MQ server say that there might be something wrong with the keys or certificate. But I know there's nothing wrong with these because I tested the C++ solution on multiple QManagers with TLS channels. The Perl solution does not work in the exact same circumstances.

There are those additional settings in connectOpts (MQCNO struct), which I wasn't able to simulate in Perl (so I assume they are not as important there). Also, I hope that the positional nature of MQCD and MQSCO structs has no impact on Perl handling of the hashes.
I don't see any typo in my connection options (and if there was any, Params::Validate takes care of the validation in QueueManager).

If it's of any use, the configuration of the channel is:

```
CHANNEL(CHANNEL_TLS) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
ALTDATE(2020-12-07) ALTTIME(09.30.54)
CERTLABL( ) COMPHDR(NONE)
COMPMSG(NONE)
DESCR()
DISCINT(0) HBINT(300)
KAINT(AUTO) MAXINST(300)
MAXINSTC(999999999) MAXMSGL(16777216)
MCAUSER(mqm) MONCHL(QMGR)
RCVDATA( ) RCVEXIT( )
SCYDATA( ) SCYEXIT( )
SENDDATA( ) SENDEXIT( )
SHARECNV(40) SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)
SSLCIPH(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256)
SSLPEER( ) TRPTYPE(TCP)
```

The non-TLS channel simply has SSLCIPH empty.

PS: This is the response in /var/mqm/errors/AMQERR01.LOG:

```
01/19/2021 08:33:51 AM - Process(24037.1) User(mqm) Program(TestConnect.pl)
                    Host(localhost.localdomain) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.0.1)
                    Time(2021-01-19T08:33:51.725Z)
                    RemoteHost(10.132.4.9(1414))
                    CommentInsert1(CHANNEL_TLS)
                    CommentInsert2(host1 (10.132.4.9)(1414))

AMQ9642E: No SSL or TLS certificate for channel 'CHANNEL_TLS'.

EXPLANATION:
The channel 'CHANNEL_TLS' did not supply a certificate to use during SSL or
TLS handshaking, but a certificate is required by the remote queue manager.

The remote host is 'host1 (10.132.4.9)(1414)'.

The channel did not start.
ACTION:
Ensure that the key repository of the local queue manager or MQ client contains
a certificate which is associated with the queue manager or client. If you have
configured a certificate label, check that the certificate exists.

Alternatively, if appropriate, change the remote channel definition so that its
SSLCAUTH attribute is set to OPTIONAL and it has no SSLPEER value set.
----- cmqxrfpt.c : 690 --------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you checked the `AMQERR01.LOG` on the client machine.   If it is a full install it would be written under `/var/mqm/errors`, if it is a redist it will write to `$HOME/IBM/MQ/data/errors`.  This should give more info about the `2393` error.

Comment: I have to ask, why go the code route? All of this can be done without changing your code? Just set a couple of env vars and use a CCDT.

Comment: @JoshMc I have edited my message to show the error. To my mind, it tells me nothing. Is it possible that the settings I provide through SSLConfig hash are ignored?? If I do not set KeyRepository, I get an explicit error 2381 saying "Key repository error", so it must be correctly set... When I remove the CertificateLabel, the error is the same as originally, which makes me think: is "CertificateLabel" key correct?? How can I check that?

Comment: @MoragHughson I checked this: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q132970_.html but none of our queue managers allow an ftp or http connection. I talked with our middleware department and it's currently unacceptable to expect CCDT to be enabled for each customer where we need to have the Perl script running. Nevertheless thanks for the hint, I will keep in contact with them.

Comment: Ok, it seems I was able to make it work. The CertificateLabel field is in fact ignored for some reason. After using this: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016920_.htm and setting MQCERTLABL instead, it seems to be working now!

Comment: You could label the cert as ibmwebspheremq**user_id**, for example if the user is `xyz` the default label MQ will look for is `ibmwebspheremqxyz`

Comment: Seems the perl mod is not allowing for that field?

Comment: Also note the ccdt does not need to be hosted on a ftp or http server, it can be a local file. With v9.2 it can even be a JSON formatted file. The key store, cert label, ccdt location can all be specified in a mqclient.ini or via ENV vars.

Comment: @genghis your comments about CCDT make no sense.  If you are giving someone the Perl script then you can also give them the CCDT file too.  Just put everything in the same directory then have the user set the MQCHLLIB and MQCHLTAB environment variables and they will be good to go.